# Flattening Complex LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

I have a somewhat complex LINQ to SQL query that I'm trying to optimise (no, not prematurely, things are slow), that goes a little bit like this;

```
IQueryable<SearchListItem> query = DbContext.EquipmentLives
    .Where(...)
    .Select(e => new SearchListItem {
        EquipmentStatusId = e.EquipmentStatuses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.DateTo == null).Id,
        StatusStartDate = e.EquipmentStatuses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.DateTo == null).DateFrom,
        ...
    });
```

The where clauses aren't important, they don't filter `EquipmentStatuses`, happy to include if someone thinks they're required.

This is on quite a large set of tables and returns a fairly details object, there's more references to `EquipmentStatuses`, but I'm sure you get the idea. The problem is that there's quite obviously two sub-queries and I'm sure that (among some other things) is not ideal, especially since they are exactly the same sub-query each time.

Is it possible to flatten this out a bit? Perhaps it's easier to do a few smaller queries to the database and create the `SearchListItem` in a `foreach` loop?

Comment: As you said, *smaller queries* IMO is going to improve your performance significantly. 
You can get a list of those EquipmentStatuses with fields that you need in you SearchListItem, and then with a foreach.[AsParallel](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/3569/parallel-linq-plinq#t=201612160723395391103) you can fill SearchListItem.

Comment: If you have a complex LINQ query it probably means you have a design problem. Either missing mappings, or the query should actually be a view in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take given your comments, and with some assumptions I've made

- It may look scary, but give it a try, with and without the `ToList()` before the GroupBy()
- If you have LinqPad, check the SQL produced, and the number of queries, or just plug in the SQL Server Profiler
- With LinqPad you could even put a `Stopwatch` to measure things precisely

Enjoy ;)

```
var query = DbContext.EquipmentLives
    .AsNoTracking() // Notice this!!!
    .Where(...)

    // WARNING: SelectMany is an INNER JOIN
    // You won't get EquipmentLive records that don't have EquipmentStatuses
    // But your original code would break if such a case existed
    .SelectMany(e => e.EquipmentStatuses, (live, status) => new
    {
        EquipmentLiveId = live.Id, // We'll need this one for grouping
        EquipmentStatusId = status.Id,
        EquipmentStatusDateTo = status.DateTo,
        StatusStartDate = status.DateFrom
        //...
    })

    // WARNING: Again, you won't get EquipmentLive records for which none of their EquipmentStatuses have a DateTo == null
    // But your original code would break if such a case existed
    .Where(x => x.EquipmentStatusDateTo == null)

    // Now You can do a ToList() before the following GroupBy(). It depends on a lot of factors...
    // If you only expect one or two EquipmentStatus.DateTo == null per EquipmentLive, doing ToList() before GroupBy may give you a performance boost
    // Why? GroupBy sometimes confuses the EF SQL generator and the SQL Optimizer
    .GroupBy(x => x.EquipmentLiveId, x => new SearchListItem
    {
        EquipmentLiveId = x.EquipmentLiveId, // You may or may not need this?
        EquipmentStatusId = x.EquipmentStatusId,
        StatusStartDate = x.StatusStartDate,
        //...
    })

    // Now you have one group of SearchListItem per EquipmentLive
    // Each group has a list of EquipmenStatuses with DateTo == null
    // Just select the first one (you could do g.OrderBy... as well)
    .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())

    // Materialize
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to repeat the `FirstOrDefault`. You can add an intermediate `Select` to select it once and then reuse it:

```
IQueryable<SearchListItem> query = DbContext.EquipmentLives
    .Where(...)
    .Select(e => e.EquipmentStatuses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.DateTo == null))
    .Select(s => new SearchListItem {
        EquipmentStatusId = s.Id,
        StatusStartDate = s.DateFrom,
        ...
    });
```

In query syntax (which I find more readable) it would look like this:

```
var query =
    from e in DbContext.EquipmentLives
    where ...
    let s = e.EquipmentStatuses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.DateTo == null)
    select new SearchListItem {
        EquipmentStatusId = s.Id,
        StatusStartDate = s.DateFrom,
        ...
    });
```

There is another problem in your query though. If there is no matching `EquipmentStatus` in your `EquipmentLive`, `FirstOrDefault` will return `null`, which will cause an exception in the last select. So you might need an additional `Where`:

```
IQueryable<SearchListItem> query = DbContext.EquipmentLives
    .Where(...)
    .Select(e => e.EquipmentStatuses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.DateTo == null))
    .Where(s => s != null)
    .Select(s => new SearchListItem {
        EquipmentStatusId = s.Id,
        StatusStartDate = s.DateFrom,
        ...
    });
```

or

```
var query =
    from e in DbContext.EquipmentLives
    where ...
    let s = e.EquipmentStatuses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.DateTo == null)
    where s != null
    select new SearchListItem {
        EquipmentStatusId = s.Id,
        StatusStartDate = s.DateFrom,
        ...
    });
```

Comment: Good idea but that's assuming the `EquipmentStatus` object is the base that I can use to populate the `SearchListItem` object. Unfortunately I need to keep the base as `EquipmentLives` as there's quite a few other properties of `SearchListItem` that required the `EquipmentLives` object.

Comment: That's no problem. You can still access it with `e`.

Comment: Especially in query syntax accessing your e is simple. Just use it in the select.

Comment: Correct, but I don't fancy rewriting the method syntax into query syntax and in the method syntax example you've provided, `EquipmentLives` is not accessible. I think you'd need to make it a `SelectMany` like the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't test for null after calling `FirstOrDefault(s => s.DateTo == null)` I assume that:

- either **for each device there is always a status with `DateTo == null`** or
- you need to see **only devices which have such status**

In order to do so you need to join `EquipmentLives` with `EquipmentStatuses` to avoid subqueries:

```
var query = DbContext.EquipmentLives
    .Where(l => true)
    .Join(DbContext.EquipmentStatuses.Where(s => s.DateTo == null),
        eq => eq.Id,
        status => status.EquipmentId,
        (eq, status) => new SelectListItem
        {
            EquipmentStatusId = status.Id,
            StatusStartDate = status.DateFrom
        });
```

However, if you do want to perform a `left join` replace `DbContext.EquipmentStatuses.Where(s => s.DateTo == null)` with `DbContext.EquipmentStatuses.Where(s => s.DateTo == null).DefaultIfEmpty()`.